# vue: v-else does not completely show context

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue. When I use v-if, v-else-if, and v-else, the first two tags work well. But for v-else, it only change the context in {{}}.

html:

```
<div id="app">
<div v-if="isIf === 1">
  isIf is 1：{{isIf}}
</div>
<div v-else-if="2">
  isIf is 2：{{isIf}}
</div>
<div v-else>
  isIf is not 1 or 2：{{isIf}}
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
  <script>
 var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isIf: 1,
    isShow: false
  }
});
</script>
```

when I change the app.isIf=3 in console, it showed isIf is 2: 3. My last try is app.isIf=2, so it showed the context with last input. Any idea?

Comment: You have to add condition for `v-else-if` like `v-if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-else-if` condition is wrong - instead of

```
<div v-else-if="2">
```

it should be

```
<div v-else-if="isIf === 2">
```

Except for zero, any numerical value will be considered "true" in Javascripts. So your render logic is always around "v-if" and "v-else-if", it never reaches "v-else"